Why is npm install running forever (behind a corporate proxy)?
Running npm install behind a proxy is running forever or very slow (so slow that I never waited for it to complete), without anything helpful in the logs.
What can be the root cause?
I wanted to post my answer below directly as an answer of this other question that is quite a duplicate but not fully a duplicate since it does not mention the problems related to corporate proxy:
Why is "npm install" really slow?
This is not allowed for me yet since I do not have enough reputation and this question indicates "Highly active question. Earn 10 reputation (not counting the association bonus) in order to answer this question. The reputation requirement helps protect this question from spam and non-answer activity."
I ran

npm install

I expected the installation to complete but it never ended and populated only a few folders under the sub directory "node_modules".
I am using node v20.18.0, npm 10.8.2 on a Windows VM.

"The reputation requirement helps protect this question from spam and non-answer activity." and this isn't an answer, so the system seems to have worked.

@jonrsharpe : you were right when you posted your comment yesterday that this was not a valid answer. I had to wait before my question was actually published so that I could post my answer below. You happen to have seen my partial contribution and commented before I took the time to add my answer. If you downvoted my question, could you please revert this or explain why? If there is a better way for me to share this knowledge please let me know, I can change to be more useful for the community.

In my case, behind a proxy, I had to provide a valid entry in the npm configuration file located at
%userprofile%\.npmrc

The line I had to include was
registry="http://specific.value.to.be.adapted/.../"

npm could then know where it's company specific repository was located and it started working as expected and downloaded the project dependency in a decent time.
